# Text-indent has effect on the first child span element of div?

Tags: html, css, firefox, text-indent

here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/zz89emkr/1/

```
.menu-items {
  width: 400px;
  text-indent: 5%;
}    
<div class="menu-items">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus quia maiores voluptatum adipisci iusto perferendis earum quasi, accusamus magni temporibus alias consectetur, provident vel quis nesciunt expedita sit nemo aliquam?</span>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo quas esse eius. Quos atque ea necessitatibus labore est error hic. At quae veritatis sit aperiam debitis animi provident dolorum dolore?</div>
    <span>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque, eaque atque adipisci, fugiat fuga maiores repellendus voluptas non explicabo odio et ut tenetur sint iusto minima unde. Ex, voluptas sed?</span>
</div>
```

I know that text-indent will not work on inline element, however, in this example, the first span will get text-indent. What's more, in firefox, the text-indent in the first span element is larger than that in the div element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Text-indent has effect on the first child span

No, actually the indentation has nothing to do with the `span`. Being that you have set `text-indent` on a block element - `.menu-items` - indentation will be applied before:

1) The first element/node in the container - regardless of whether that element is `inline` or `block` or whether the element is text or other content (such as an image) and...

2) All subsequent block level text elements in the container (*)(see below)

```css
.wpr {
  text-indent: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wpr">
  This is just a regular text node. However, since it's the <strong>first node</strong> in the container - it is indented (due to text-indent being set on the wrapper div)
  <p>This is some block level text - it's indented</p>
  <span>Here is some inline level text</span>
  <div>Here's some more block level text - again, indented</div>
  This text node is <strong>not indented</strong>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="wpr">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt=""> 
  <p>Notice that the image above is indented (it's the first element in the container) This block level text - so it's also indented</p>
  <span>Here is some inline level text</span>
  <div>Here's some more block level text - again, indented</div>
  This text node is <strong>not indented</strong>
</div>
```

> What's more, in firefox, the text-indent in the first span element is
>   larger than that in the div element

Firstly, this discrepancy on firefox can only be reproduced when:

1) The container element has a set width (less than the viewport width)

2) `text-indent` is set with a **percentage** value

3) The first element in container is not block level

(All 3 criteria are present in the example fiddle you provided)

This looks like **a bug**, since **firefox** renders the indentation (before the first element) as a percentage value of the **viewport width** instead of a percentage of the **container width**!

[**Codepen Demo**](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/VrWgQZ) (Resize in firefox to see this - and keep your eye on the indentation of the first line)

Being that [The spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#text-indent-property) clearly states (bold mine):

> Percentages:  refers to width of **containing block**

...I'd say that firefox is doing it wrong.

---

(*) That's my understanding of what is said in the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#text-indent-property):

> Unless otherwise specified by the each-line and/or hanging keywords,
>   only lines that are the **first formatted line** [CSS21] of an element
>   are affected. For example, the first line of an anonymous block box is
>   only affected if it is the first child of its parent element.

[The spec elsewhere](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#first-line-pseudo) elaborates on the meaning of "first formatted line":

> The "first formatted line" of an element may occur inside a
>   block-level descendant in the same flow (i.e., a block-level
>   descendant that is not positioned and not a float). E.g., the first
>   line of the DIV in `<DIV><P>This line...</P></DIV>` is the first line of
>   the P (assuming that both P and DIV are block-level).

Comment: I see, then it is a bug in Firefox for indenting more space?

Comment: @hongcarl - I updated this answer - I do think it's a bug and I explain why

Comment: I still have a little doubt about text-indent in your explanation. As you mentioned in 1) The first element/node in the container - regardless of whether that element is inline or block. In the spec , it says [This property specifies the indentation applied to lines of inline content in a block](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#text-indent-property), which makes more sense to me.

Comment: To my understanding : 1. <div class="menu-items"><span>lore...</span</div>, the div has text-indent effect on the inline span content.  2. <div class="menu-items"><div>lore....</div</div>,  the parent div has no first inline content, so text-indent won't take effect. however, the child div inherits text-indent and has first inline content, so it will indent.

Answer (score 0):

Give `display:block` to `.menu-items span` because `span` default behavior is `inline-block`.

```css
.menu-items {
  width: 400px;
  text-indent: 5%;
}
.menu-items span{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-items">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus quia maiores voluptatum adipisci iusto perferendis earum quasi, accusamus magni temporibus alias consectetur, provident vel quis nesciunt expedita sit nemo aliquam?</span>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo quas esse eius. Quos atque ea necessitatibus labore est error hic. At quae veritatis sit aperiam debitis animi provident dolorum dolore?</div>
    <span>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque, eaque atque adipisci, fugiat fuga maiores repellendus voluptas non explicabo odio et ut tenetur sint iusto minima unde. Ex, voluptas sed?</span>
  </div>
```

Comment: I know span is inline element, however, in the jsfiddle, text-indent works on the first span, which is not expected.

Comment: `text-indent` works on all child element of `.menu-items` parent div. You don't want to give `text-indent` to `span` tag...?

Comment: then why the second span doesn't get text-indent?

Comment: Please see carefully second span also get text-indent in my solution. For this you have to give `display:block`  to `span` tag.

Comment: I'm sorry if I don't get myself understood. I read your answer, and I get your point. You can click jsfiddle link in the description to see for yourself, the first span element will indent, but the second span element doesn't indent.